# "Sober as a judge" vs. "Drunk as a lord". Why judge? Why lord?

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown, simile

*Sober as a judge* is a simile that is used for someone completely sober.

*Drunk as a lord* is a simile that is used for someone completely drunk.

Why is judge equated with sobriety and lord with insobriety?

What is the origin of these phrases?

---

We can guess that judges shouldn't drink during duty hours but why specifically this occupation? We can also guess that lords were drinking a lot in the olden times and that's why it might be associated. But why not "drunk as a king"?

I did some research and "drunk as a king' is used indeed; but it is very uncommon and appears in a very few sources.

> They tell you “he's as drunk as a beast;” then, again, we are constantly hearing of a man “as drunk as Chloe,” or “as drunk as a lord,” “as drunk as a king,” or “as drunk as a —,” anything, in fact, that never gets drunk at all.
>
> <sub>Will-O'-the-Wisp. 1869</sub>

According to *OED*, *Drunk as a Lord* first appears in John Evelyn's *A character of England* in 1659:

> The Gentlemen are most of them very intemperate, yet the Proverb goes, As drunk as a Lord.

And *sober as a Judge* first appears in T. D'Urfey's *Injured Princess* in 1682:

> Never fear me man, I am sober as a Judge.

---

[image]

[comedycard.co.uk](http://www.comedycard.co.uk/products/funny-birthday-card-drama-queen-sober-as-a-judge)

Comment: I think the "sober" in "sober  as a judge" derives from the other, non-alcohol-related senses of "serious, calm, gravid, patient" [etc](http://i.word.com/idictionary/sober). These characteristics are all related to (now) more common sense of not-drunk, because when you're drunk you don't exhibit any of them. In other words: a judge could not do his job drunk. By contrast, when you think of a "Lord", you shouldn't be picturing a modern MP, you should be picturing a medieval princeling who had nothing but money and time in a world without movies or 2048. They were drunk a *lot*.

Comment: In short: judges are sober because they have a job to do. Lords are drunk because they *don't*.

Comment: Possibly, the metaphor *sober as a judge* is connected to the Gin Craze which became epidemic in the early 18th century [‘Most of the Murders and Robberies lately committed’, said the London Grand Jury (Anonymous, 1736a), ‘have been laid and concentrated at Gin Shops’](http://alcalc.oxfordjournals.org/content/36/5/401.full) The phenonmena of alcohol induced crimes was not new but in London in the 1700s the numbers reached epic proportions.

Comment: Prisoner: "I was drunk as a judge." Court: "Surely you mean 'drunk as a lord'?" P: "Yes, my lord."

Comment: @TimLymington: That's hilarious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Drunk as a Lord***

John Ray, [*A Collection of English Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rnlQoxh95VMC&pg=PA283&dq=%22drunk+as+a+lord%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GkNBVc6dNM6qogTQtYH4BA&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20lord%22&f=false) (1678) has an interesting comment on "drunk as a lord," which he views as having supplanted the older "drunk as a beggar": <sup>1</sup>

> As drunk as a beggar
>
> > This Proverb begins now to be disused, and in stead of it people are ready to say, As drunk as a Lord : so much hath that vice (the more is the pity) prevail'd among the Nobility and Gentry of late years.

Indeed, the expression "drunk as a beggar" seems to have been so largely forgotten by 1800 that the author of "[The Manners of the Great Not Essential to the Manners of the Nation](https://books.google.com/books?id=h9cPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA747&dq=%22drunk+as+a+lord%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DFpBVYjXJ8_EogS_ooDQDQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20lord%22&f=false)," in *The Scots Magazine* (November 1799) seizes upon "drunk as a lord" as an instance of popular opinion holding the aristocracy to a higher standard than they apply to everyone else:

> Still, however the situation of the great is so eminent, that it is impossible for us to take our eyes off, and continually viewing men of high distinction, we are apt to imagine there must be something highly distinguished even in their follies ; that a debt contracted by a lord has something more faulty than one contracted by a tradesman ; that an amour between two right honourables is something more licentious than one between a plain master and miss, and that a shopkeeper cannot possibly arrive at the wickedness of being "**as drunk as a lord**."

Nathan Bailey, [*Dictionarium Britannicum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O50-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PT286&dq=%22drunk+as+a+lord%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kVpBVZC6Oo6uogTEuIHQCQ&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCDgU#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20lord%22&f=false) (1736) offers this comment on the phrase "as drunk as beggars":

> **as DRUNK as beggars**
>
> By this proverb one would be apt to judge this vice was formerly peculiar only to the meaner sort of people. But experience as well as a saying, now more us'd, (As drunk as a lord) teaches us that it has got footing among the Nobility.

"[The Feast of Wit: Or, Sportsman's Hall](https://books.google.com/books?id=E5waAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA243&dq=%22drunk+as+a+beggar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SEhBVZ7dN4W5ogTAloGYAQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20beggar%22&f=false)," in *Sporting Magazine* (July 1793)—offers a joke based on the various "drunk as a" similes then extant:

> As drunk *as an owl*, as drunk *as a sow*, as drunk *as a beggar*, as drunk *as the devil*, **as drunk *as a lord***. These are the principal comparisons of drunkenness, and the explanation is as follows:—a man is as drunk *as an owl*, when *he cannot see* ; he is as drunk *as a sow* when *he tumbles in the dirt* ; he is as drunk *as a beggar*, when *he is very impudent* ; he is as drunk *as the devil*, when *he is inclined to mischief* ; and **as drunk *as a lord***, when *he is every thing that is bad*.

Ebenezer Brewer, [*Dictionary of Phrase and Fable*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IgjAJazrBWwC&pg=PA367&dq=%22drunk+as+a+beggar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_UxBVe_2DJGsoQTJ0oHwAw&ved=0CCMQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20beggar%22&f=false) (Wordsworth reprint 2001) has this note on "drunk as a lord":

> *Drunk as a lord.* Before the great temperance movement set in, in the latter half of the 19th century, those who could afford to drink thought it quite *comme il faut* to drink two, three, or even more bottles of port wine for dinner, and few dinners ended without placing the guests under the table in a hopeless state of intoxication ; hence the expression.

---

***Sober as a Judge***

Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (1997) has an interesting (though roundabout) theory of the origin of this phrase:

> **sober as a judge.** In the play [*Don Quixote in England*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QndZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22sober+as+a+judge%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WaxBVYyTJJLioATj5IHQBA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22sober%20as%20a%20judge%22&f=false) (1734) one of Henry Fielding's characters [who is quite drunk and is behaving outrageously] says: "I am as sober as a judge." Perhaps it was simply Fielding's observation that judges are almost always sober on the bench, but the phrase may have its source in the saying AN APPEAL FROM PHILIP DRUNK TO PHILIP SOBER. Sober is the exact opposite of the Latin word for "in his cups," deriving from *so*, "apart from," and *bria*, "cup."

Hendrickson's entry for that phrase is as follows:

> **appeal from Philip drunk to Philip sober.** A woman petitioned King Philip of Macedon [the father of Alexander the Great] for justice for her husband and was refused. "I shall appeal against this judgment!" she exclaimed, and Philip—while still in his cups—roared: "Appeal—and to whom will you appeal?" "To Philip sober," the woman replied, and according to Valerius Maximus, who tells the tale, she won her case.

The connection between the "sober as a judge" saying and the "appeal to Philip sober" saying is clever and appealing (in a Philip sober way), but it would be more plausible if (1) the earliest instance of "sober as a judge" weren't from 1682 (as the OP reports; the earliest Google Books matches are from [1701](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jw8UAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA19&dq=%22sober+as+a+judge%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EcNBVZPyA8zaoASE_4GABw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22sober%20as%20a%20judge%22&f=false) and [1702](https://books.google.com/books?id=bslbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22sober+as+a+judge%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_cFBVYqdKZTVoATur4HYAg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22sober%20as%20a%20judge%22&f=false)), and (2) the earliest reference to the "Philip sober" story in a Google Books search weren't from 77 years later, in a [letter by David Hume to the editor](https://books.google.com/books?id=iHAJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA112&dq=%22appeal+from+Philip%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gr9BVYOLAc7HogTNo4DgAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAzgU#v=onepage&q=%22appeal%20from%20Philip%22&f=false) of *The Critical Review*, dated April 1759:

> I appeal from your sentence, as an old woman did from a sentence pronounced by Philip of Macedon:—I appeal from Philip, ill-counselled and in a hurry, to Philip, well-advised, and judging with deliberation.

A second instance occurs in a [Parliamentary debate](https://books.google.com/books?id=RAcxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PT215&dq=%22APPEAL+FROM+PHILIP+DRUNK+TO+PHILIP+SOBER%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x7NBVaaMJMeoogTq7IHACg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAzgo#v=onepage&q=%22APPEAL%20FROM%20PHILIP%20DRUNK%20TO%20PHILIP%20SOBER%22&f=false) of February 7, 1799:

> He [Mr. Windham] had no doubt but that, when the present fury should have evaporated, he should see the people of Ireland as eager for the measure [Union with the United Kingdom] as they now were against it. ... He wished, therefore, to **appeal from Philip drunk to Philip sober** ; he wished to appeal from the Irish, mad with independence, that is to say, independent of reason, independent of argument, to the Irish in a fit mood to examine the proposition that was offered them.

But the timing seems wrong for the "Philip sober" story to have strongly influenced "sober as a judge" in English idiomatic usage.

### ------------------

<sup>1</sup>Robert Dent, [*Proverbial Language in English Drama Exclusive of Shakespeare, 1495–1616*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oYDMndXNWlUC&pg=PA202&dq=%22drunk+as+a+beggar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_UxBVe_2DJGsoQTJ0oHwAw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20beggar%22&f=false), volume 2 (1984) gives a first occurrence date of 1616 for "drunk as a beggar," but also mentions earlier possible occurrences from 1612 and 1609. Fynes Moryson, [*A Description of Ireland*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XDUNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA428&dq=%22drunk+as+beggars%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8FxBVcXFOM_xoATepYFQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20beggars%22&f=false) (between 1603 and 1616) uses the expression "as drunk as beggars": "And not only the common sort, but even the lords and their wives, the more they want this drink [Spanish wine or Irish usquebaugn] at home the more they swallow it when they come to it, till they be **as drunk as beggars**." Earlier still is this instance from Walter Raleigh, [*The Discovery of Guiana*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bJcdAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA222&dq=%22drunk+as+beggars+and+the+pots%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aGFBVY3nBsrgoAS874HABw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20beggars%20and%20the%20pots%22&f=false) (1596): "But when we came in first to the House of the said Timitwara, being upon one of their Feast-Days, we found them all **as drunk as Beggars**, and the Pots walking from one to another, without rest : ..." A servant's remark in Shakespeare's *Antony and Cleopatra* (1607) about the inebriation of Lepidus—"Lepidus is high Conlord/They haue made him drinke Almes drinke."—prompts this comment in Hilda Hulme, "[The Spoken Language and the Dramatic Text](https://books.google.com/books?id=OxgDsNkpCVUC&pg=PA151&dq=%22drunk+as+a+beggar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_UxBVe_2DJGsoQTJ0oHwAw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22drunk%20as%20a%20beggar%22&f=false)," in *A Reader in the Language of Shakespearean Drama* (1987): "There would, I suggest, be no difficulty of interpretation could we suppose that, with the words 'drink alms-drink' the servant is merely changing the known idiom '**drunk as a beggar**', getting his laugh by delaying recognition of a current phrase."

Answer (score 2):

A judge sitting on the bench certainly ought to be sober.  Also, **sober** also means serious, and a judge in a case certainly is serious so this might even be the ultimate origin of the phrase.

As to the other, young sons of the nobility were notorious partiers, and had lordships until their fathers died.  Young, no responsibilities, money, and the ability to get out of most legal scrapes leads to a number of memorable scenes.

Comment: I said much the same thing in the comments, but I didn't post it as an answer because I didn't want to go through the effort of substantiating it etymologically. If you do, I've got a +1 waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

The origin appears to be from commonsense ( a sober judge) and drinking habits ( of Lords).

[Sober as a judge](http://www.kgbanswers.co.uk/where-does-the-phrase-as-sober-as-a-judge-come-from/3685084)

> - Why judges should be equated with sobriety is not known, but the simile was first recorded in 1694. Possibly due to there important staus in society

[Drunk as a Lord](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/42/messages/1465.html)

> - It just means really drunk. Why "as a lord"? Well, I know very little about English peers, but I suppose some of them used to drink heavily. The expression dates from around 1891 or before.
> - In the 1700s and 1800s overindulgence was considered a sign of gentility and was considered gentlemanly.
> - Back then men of status would vie in a one-upmanship of drinking each other under the table---hence your simile.

Source:http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/42/messages/1465.html

Answer (score 0):

Sober as a judge may refer to evenhandedness in rendering a judicial decision ("sober" is used metaphorically then, to refer to clarity of mind, as when one is not influenced by drugs or alcohol)