# "I'm happy to see that you are sober as a judge" Is this a rhetorical device?

Tags: figures-of-speech, rhetorical-devices

Context: A few decades ago, during the electoral campaign for governor, there was a televised debate between the three major parties candidates. Candidate A, the favorite according to the polls, was notorious for heavy drinking and rumor had it that he had become a real alcoholic.  The three candidates arrived at the studio and when Candidate C shook hands with Candidate A he said: It's a great pleasure to meet you, Mr A, and **"I'm happy to see that you are sober as a judge".**  Candidate A simply smiled and said "Thank you", perhaps hoping it had gone unnoticed.

First I thought this might be a figure of speech like "Ad hominem, poisoning the well".  Then again, it doesn't look or sound like a figure of speech.  Is it a rhetorical device? What kind? Is there a term for it?

Comment: Ad homin*em*.  The trope itself is just a simile; it's use might be called innuendo.

Comment: "Sober as a judge" is an old expression meaning, simply, very sober, without any obvious impairment from intoxication, and perhaps quite dull and dreary in demeanor.  I'd say it's simply being used as a left-handed compliment.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190613/sober-as-a-judge-vs-drunk-as-a-lord-why-judge-why-lord

Comment: @ermanen - a google-search revealed (*for the first time*) your OP to me, which I enjoyed and +1'd earlier today (it deserved a better reception, IMO), also re-posted Mr. Lymington's hilarious commentary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be [paralipsis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/P/paralipsis.htm):

> Stating and drawing attention to something in the very act of pretending to pass it over. A kind of irony.  (From the Silva Rhetoricae website at Brigham Young University)

I say "might", because it's a term I only recently came across, and the remark in your question is more oblique than the example on the page I linked to (which, as it happens, also involves accusing a politician of drinking).  But the intention is clearly the same, and on the Wikipedia page for paralipsis (which redirects to [apophasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis)), another example is given in which Ronald Reagan implies something about a political opponent in a similarly oblique manner:

> When asked about the allegations that Dukakis had received psychological treatment in the past, Reagan responded by saying with a smile, "Look, I’m not going to pick on an invalid".  (Wikipedia)

If that is indeed paralipsis/apophasis, then I would say that, in this context, "I'm happy to see that you are sober as a judge" is too.

Comment: Please cite the source of your material and link, in case the link becomes obsolete or suffers link-rot.

Comment: Agreed with @LittleEva. There no pretence to gloss over his inebriation here. A paralipsis would be something like: "Let's not dwell on you being sober for the first time ever."

Comment: @LittleEva: Thanks for the kind words. I'm happy to compete with friendly, fair-minded people like yourself! :)

Comment: @TusharRaj: I think it comes down to how literal you require the speaker's counter-claim (i.e., the claim not to be bringing the negative topic up) to be.  "Let's not dwell" and the like are explicit counter-claims, but I would argue that in the OP's example the counter-claim is implicit in the carefully constructed *appearance* of saying something positive about the other man.  (Perhaps there's another, different term for this though?)

Comment: A clever example of paralipsis/apophasis: Prisoner: "I was drunk as a judge." Court: "Surely you mean 'drunk as a lord'?" P: "Yes, my lord."  – [**Comment by Tim Lymington**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190613/sober-as-a-judge-vs-drunk-as-a-lord-why-judge-why-lord)  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> [**Double Entendre**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=double+entendre+meaning&gws_rd=ssl): ambiguity of meaning arising from language that lends itself to more than one interpretation. (Google)
>
> [**Sober**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sober) *adjective*
>
> **1**: sparing in the use of food and drink: abstemious.
>
> **2**: marked by sedate or gravely or earnestly thoughtful character or demeanor.
>
> (Merriam-Webster *online*)

---

> [**Sober: *etymology***](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sober&allowed_in_frame=0): mid-14c., "moderate in desires or actions, temperate, restrained," especially "abstaining from strong drink," also "calm, quiet, not overcome by emotion," from Old French *sobre* "decent; sober" (12c.), from Latin *sobrius* "not drunk, temperate, moderate, sensible," from a variant of *se*- "without" (see se-) + *ebrius* "drunk," of unknown origin. Meaning "not drunk at the moment" is from late 14c.; also "appropriately solemn, serious, not giddy." Related: Soberly; soberness. Sobersides "sedate, serious-minded person" is recorded from 1705. (etymonline)

---

The adjective *sober* has several distinct meanings, two of which are in play here.

---

> [**Sober as a Judge**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sober+as+a+judge) *idiom / simile*
>
> **1**. *Cliché* very formal, somber, or stuffy. (*Also: as ~.) You certainly look gloomy, Bill. You're sober as a judge. Tom's as sober as a judge. I think he's angry.
>
> **2**. *Cliché* not drunk; alert and completely sober. (*Also: as ~.) John's drunk? No, he's as sober as a judge. You should be sober as a judge when you drive a car. (The Free Dictionary)

---

So, within this rather clever turn of phrase I can see two double *entendres* operating - one based on the two distinct senses of the term "sober," and the other utilizing the fixed phrase "sober as a judge," to mean both **1)** “sober as a judge” which plays upon the reputation – deserved or not – for the *propriety* of judges (serious, grave, solemn, sedate, staid, earnest), and **2)** a literal, rather than figurative, take on the simile, i.e., "I'm happy to see you are abstemious when acting in the official capacity as a judge."

---

Comment: I can only see one meaning here -- the implication that Mr. A is a drunk.  What's the other meaning?  (Is it that a governor is a type of judge?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker  That's it.

Comment: Ah, so there's a double meaning on "sober" *and* a clever connection with "judge" :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker No double meaning in the phrase "sober as a judge", just the usual idiomatic meaning.  The insult comes from "I'm happy to see . . ." suggesting that one might have expected otherwise.

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede - even when abstracted from all context, standing alone, "sober as a judge" is capable of two interpretations due to the two disparate senses of the adjective sober. When the phrase is recontextualized within the OP's explicitly political setting, another interpretation opens up, i.e., a *literal* rather then the merely *figurative* understanding of "as a judge."

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the question is asking for the name of this type of remark.

It has been pointed out already that 'sober as a judge' is a well known expression.

As a whole however, I interpret the comment as a deliberate slight; he wanted to highlight his opponent's alcoholism in a somewhat indirect manner.

Hence, in British English, the comment could be labelled as a ***[snide remark](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snide)***.

> **Snide:** (of a remark, etc) maliciously derogatory; supercilious

CED as found at thefreedictionary.com

Also, I think that it was rather ***sarcastic***.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a rhetorical device; it is an oxymoron. I'm highly surprised "sober as a judge" does not show up on any online list of oxymorons. It should. There are too many media-documented instances of judges' drunken, public conduct in existence to dismiss the saying's oxymoronic—even sarcastic—stature.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't heard this variant before but The Free Dictionary says it means you're "[to not at all drunk](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+as+sober+as+a+judge)". The comparison to an honorable man of the law, who presumably would not drink very much, is probably just meant to intensify the sentiment that you're sober.

If I wanted to get the sentiment I probably would've said "[sober as a priest on sunday](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0041858/quotes)" (Internet Movie Database, quoting Seamus McFly from Back to the Future III) myself.

> be as sober as a judge. (n.d.) Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.. (2006) retrieved from The Free Dictionary by Farlex.